# Time between first and latest commit

Tags: git

How can I get the time (in hours or days) between first and latest commit in git? If I want for example know how long I am working with project.

Comment: Use `git log --format=%ct <commit>` to get the Unix timestamp of the commit identified by `<commit>`. Use the same to get the timestamp of the last commit. Subtract them to get the number of seconds between them. Compute the number of days etc. Or use `git log --pretty=%cr <commit>` to get the time that passed since that commit has been created, directly in a human-friendly format. This is not useful to get the difference between two commits, though. Read more about [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) (or run `git help log` in your terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [the display of time difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27013/displaying-seconds-as-days-hours-mins-seconds):

```
function displayDuration {
  local T=$1
  local Y=$((T/60/60/24/365))
  local D=$((T/60/60/24%365))
  local H=$((T/60/60%24))
  local M=$((T/60%60))
  local S=$((T%60))
  (( $Y > 0 )) && printf '%d years ' $Y
  (( $D > 0 )) && printf '%d days ' $D
  (( $H > 0 )) && printf '%d hours ' $H
  (( $M > 0 )) && printf '%d minutes ' $M
  (( $D > 0 || $H > 0 || $M > 0 )) && printf 'and '
  printf '%d seconds\n' $S
}

displayDuration $(expr $(git log --pretty=format:%at | head -1) - $(git log --reverse --pretty=format:%at | head -1))
```